# ChefSpec matcher for execute when action is :nothing?

Tags: chef

Writing some testing for a semi-complicated setup. I need to reload `systemd` after removing some init script installed by a package.

`pager.rb`:

```
execute 'systemctl daemon-reload' do
  action :nothing
end

...

file '/etc/init.d/pdagent' do
  notifies :run, 'execute[systemctl daemon-reload]', :immediately
  action :delete
end
```

This all works, but I'm having trouble writing a ChefSpec test suite for the [execute block](https://docs.chef.io/resource_execute.html). Seth Vargo's [examples](https://github.com/sethvargo/chefspec/blob/master/examples/execute/spec/run_spec.rb) show a matcher for run_execute, but using it for `action :nothing` fails:

`spec.rb`:

```
it do
  expect(chef_run).to run_execute('systemctl daemon-reload')
end
```

results in:

> Failure/Error: expect(chef_run).to run_execute('systemctl
>   daemon-reload')
>          expected "execute[systemctl daemon-reload]" actions [] to include :run
>        # ./spec/pagerduty_spec.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there's a fairly generic [do_nothing](https://github.com/sethvargo/chefspec/blob/master/examples/do_nothing/spec/default_spec.rb) matcher:

> expect(execute).to do_nothing

Comment: I suppose I was expecting something specific to a given resource, which explains why I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

In modern Chef, matchers take the form of `action_resource`. So, when you write `expect(chef_run).to run_execute('my command')`, what you're specifying is that the resource `execute 'my command'` converges with the action `:run`. Instead, you want to match action `:nothing`, so you'd write:

`expect(chef_run).to nothing_execute('my command')`